# Boostrap sidebar parent menu link not showing submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a sidebar menu using bootstrap, on Shopify to loop through a nested menu structure at 3 levels. The problem i am facing is that the parent menu does not link to the collection page by default, it only shows the child and grandchild menus via and the Pseudo :after element.

I am aware that Pseudo elements cant be selected using jQuery, so i have added a simple function to target the URL for the parent menu which adds the URL, which is fine, but i would like for the  .collapsible:after element to still show the submenu, while `<span class="nav-test">` goes to the URL. See code below;

HTML markup

```
    {% for link in linklists[settings.mobile_linklist].links %}
    {% if link.links != blank %}
      <div class="nav-menu">
        <ul id="accordion">

          <li class="accordion">
            <span class="nav-test">
              <a href="{{ link.url }}"
               aria-controls="collapseOne"
               aria-expanded="false"
               class="collapsible"
               data-target="#collapse{{forloop.index}}"
               data-toggle="collapse">{{ link.title }}
              </a>
            </span>
            <!-- Sub menu -->
            <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="sub-menu collapse" id="collapse{{forloop.index}}">
              <ul>
                {% for childlink in link.links %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{childlink.url}}"
                    aria-controls="collapseOne"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    class="collapsible"
                    data-target="#collapse2{{forloop.index}}"
                    data-toggle="collapse">{{childlink.title}}
                </a>
                  <ul id="collapse2{{forloop.index}}">
                    {% for grandchild_link in childlink.links %}
                    <li>
                      <a href="{{grandchild_link.url}}">{{grandchild_link.title}}</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </div>

          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Script to add a URL

```
  $(function($) {
    $('.nav-test > a').click(function(){
      location.href = this.href;
    });
  });
```

CSS

```
#aside_main .side-inner .nav-menu ul li.active a:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 4px; 
}

#aside_main .side-inner .nav-menu ul li .collapsible {
  position: relative; 
}

#aside_main .side-inner .nav-menu ul li .collapsible:after {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  content: " ";
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='Icon Icon--select-arrow' role='presentation' viewBox='0 0 19 12'%3E%3Cpolyline fill='none' stroke='currentColor' points='17 2 9.5 10 2 2' fill-rule='evenodd' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='square'%3E%3C/polyline%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat;
  color: #1C1B1B;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: .3s transform ease;
  -o-transition: .3s transform ease;
  transition: .3s transform ease; 
}

#aside_main .side-inner .nav-menu ul li .collapsible[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  color: #000; 
}

#aside_main .side-inner .nav-menu ul li .collapsible[aria-expanded="true"]:before {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 4px; 
}

#aside_main .side-inner .nav-menu ul li .collapsible[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has multiple time a link so you have to provide the specific parent node too

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .parents() method allows us to search through the ancestors of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements ordered from immediate parent on up

```
 $(function($) {
    $('.nav-test > a').click(function(){
      location.href = this.parents.href;
    });
  });
```